# download NASA Earth Exchange Global Daily Downscaled Projections for single lat lon

Tags: climate-change, gis, nasa

I have a lat lon - 23.14, 83.14 and I need to download the NASA Earth Exchange Global Daily Downscaled Projections (NEX-GDDP) data from the below website only for this lat lon.

https://dataserver.nccs.nasa.gov/thredds/catalog/bypass/NEX-GDDP/catalog.html

Is there a tool/website/script that I can use to download the data 2040 - 2060 ? Would someone be willing to show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did download and process some of the NEX files a year or so ago. Maybe there is a more efficient way to do that now, but what I used is this R script to download the files:

```
library(RCurl)
opts = curlOptions(proxy='http://10.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx', userpwd = "you needed NEXGDDPusr:pswd at that time", netrc = TRUE)


var = c("pr","tasmax","tasmin") ##here the variables
rcp = c("rcp45", "rcp85") ##here the scenarios
mod= c("CCSM4", "GFDL-CM3", "IPSL-CM5A-MR", "MIROC5",  "inmcm4")##here the climate models
year=c(seq(2040,2060,1)) # here the time period

for (v in var) {
  for (r in rcp) {
    url<- paste0( 'http://nasanex.s3.amazonaws.com/NEX-GDDP/BCSD/', r, '/day/atmos/', v, '/r1i1p1/v1.0/', sep='') ##here the url (please, note this might be different now)
    for (m in mod) {
      for (y in year) {
        nfile<- paste0(v,'_day_BCSD_',r,"_r1i1p1_",m,'_',y,'.nc', sep='')
        url1<- paste0(url,nfile, sep='')
        destfile<-paste0('D:/NASA_NEX/',r,'/',v,'/',nfile, sep='') ##destination folder
        bin <- getBinaryURL(url1, .opts = opts)
        writeBin(bin, destfile)
        Sys.sleep(1)
        gc()
      }}}}
```

This, however downloads the global files.

The second stage would be to extract the data for the point you need. For doing this in R you can use something [like this](https://rpubs.com/markpayne/358146). In alternative you can use [CDO](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information that has the tool that you can do this

https://cds.nccs.nasa.gov/nex-gddp/

I have never use this but ran google it and found this..